# What kind of sink faucet screws are these and how do I tighten them?

Tags: kitchens, faucet

I have a loose sink faucet with screws I've never seen that holds it in place.

[image: Faucet]
[image: Bottom of faucet showing the screws]
[image: Side view]

There doesn't appear to be anything for a screwdriver or wrench to latch onto for tightening. How does one tighten these screws?

Comment: Those black things, from below? They look like rubber caps, can you try pulling them off? If not then try lifting the faucet skirt that's resting on your basin, there could be screws or nuts there.

Comment: I wasn't able to. It doesn't feel like plastic or rubber, but not 100% sure.

Comment: Can you get a picture from a side-view?

Comment: Yes, although it's a bit far away. I have updated the question with a side view picture.

Answer (score 2):

The plates marked A are tapered. Rotate them one way tightens and the other way loosens. I have only seen these a few times and did not care for them as they kept becoming loose but that was in a rental with college kids so it could have been rough handling.

Comment: Do you rotate them by hand?

Comment: I use long nose pliers to get them tighter than I can by hand.

Comment: Ran across these once.... didn't like them either...could never really get them tightened to where the faucet didn't move back and forth.+